# Doctrine ORM regex usage

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

How can I convert following MySQL query to doctrine code?

I am trying to get some values from three columns using regex.

```
    SELECT * FROM job where 
      CONCAT(title, company, description) REGEXP '^.*Officer.*$';
```

I tried this using direct SQL.

```
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM job where CONCAT(title, company, description) REGEXP '^.*Officer.*$';";
  $query = $em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
  $query->execute();
  return $this->json([
    'status' => $query->fetchAll()
  ]);
```

What am I supposed to do to get the same output using doctrine ?

Comment: Updated the questions with my code.